# python subprocess command with 2 password prompts

Tags: python, java, automation, subprocess, command

I am attempting to automate a Java tool invocation that requires two separate password inputs during its execution. The tool is `pepk.jar`, used for key encryption, and it prompts for the keystore password twice. I am trying to automate this using Python's `subprocess` module, but neither of the two methods I've attempted has worked successfully.

The Java tool needs to receive one password input, wait for me to press enter, then receive the second password input, followed by another enter. In a manual process, I would type a password, press enter, type the password again, and press enter once more.

I tried the following two methods with `subprocess`:

Method 1:

```
python
import subprocess

command = ['java', '-jar', 'pepk.jar', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'etc']
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
process.communicate(input='password')
process.communicate(input='password')

import subprocess

command = ['java', '-jar', 'pepk.jar', 'arg1', 'arg2', 'etc']
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.stdin.write(f'{password}\n')
proc.stdin.write(f'{password}\n')
proc.stdin.flush()
stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
print(stdout)
print(stderr)
```

Comment: I don't know about the particular tool you are trying to automate, but some security-oriented software reads passwords directly from the user's terminal instead of via the standard streams.  The `sudo` command does this by default, for example.  Automating responses to such password prompts is tricky, and it depends in part on the software doing the prompting.

Comment: As @JohnBollinger points out a typical tool of this sort will directly read from the tty rather than stdin. Which means you have to use a pseudo-tty (pty) to communicate with the process.